# What are robotics base on ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please give sample , thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199877/what-are-robotics-base-on-ros-?/) by [roschina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20157/roschina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can fins here [Robots Using ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1